# Why does apt-key hang?

Tags: apt, gnupg

I'm trying to install yarn on Ubuntu 18.10 but hit trouble when adding yarn's repo ...

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

... `apt-key` does not complete, and the gpg process is at 100% cpu.

Comment: Hi! Welcome at askubuntu.com! The curl process finishes OK? Have you tried to download the gpg keys separately and then add it?

Comment: Hi,Yes the key downloads as expected. The apt-key add - then hangs ...